# New line in text file using C#

Tags: c#, text-files

I'm a student who just started learning C#,

I'm trying to create Sign-Up and Login functions using text files, and save details that the user inputs into the textfile, but when I run my function again it rewrites what is already there instead of starting a new line.

This is a bit of my code that is important

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace SDD_Assessment_2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Write();
            //GetTime();
            var privInfo = SignUp();
            var FullName = Profile(privInfo);
            Profile(privInfo);
            //Test(FullName);
        }
        const string filename = "Workout.txt";
        static string[] SignUp()
        {
            string[] privinfo = new string[4];

            Console.Write("First Name: ");
            privinfo[0] = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Last Name: ");
            privinfo[1] = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Email: ");
            privinfo[2] = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Password: ");
            privinfo[3] = Console.ReadLine();

            StreamWriter NewAccount = new StreamWriter(filename);
            //NewAccount.WriteLine(privinfo[0] + "," + privinfo[1] + "," + privinfo[2] + "," + privinfo[3] + Environment.NewLine);
            File.AppendAllText(filename, privinfo[0] + ", " + privinfo[1] + "," + privinfo[2] + "," + privinfo[3] + Environment.NewLine);
            NewAccount.Close();

            return privinfo;
        }
    }
}
```

When I run it right now, it says "System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file 'filename' because it is being used by another process."

Comment: why you create StreamWriter NewAccount

Comment: Yeah, remove that `StreamWriter` as that's what has the file open when you try to write to it with `AppendAllText`.

Comment: that is so frustrating, I have been following a tutorial but it wasn't quite working for what I wanted to do and I visited 10 different sites and I merged the two together. I have spent 90 minutes trying to create a new line and all I had to do was remove 1 line to create 1 line. Thankyou!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is mostly correct. You need to change

```
StreamWriter NewAccount = new StreamWriter(filename);
//NewAccount.WriteLine(privinfo[0] + "," + privinfo[1] + "," + privinfo[2] + "," + privinfo[3] + Environment.NewLine);
File.AppendAllText(filename, privinfo[0] + ", " + privinfo[1] + "," + privinfo[2] + "," + privinfo[3] + Environment.NewLine);
NewAccount.Close();
```

to just

```
File.AppendAllText(filename, privinfo[0] + ", " + privinfo[1] + "," + privinfo[2] + "," + privinfo[3] + Environment.NewLine);
```

Your allocation of `NewAccount` opens a stream to the file, which keeps the file handle open. That means your `File.AppendAllText` can't complete, because the file was previously opened in a non-sharing mode.

If you had deleted `File.AppendAllText` you wouldn't get the error, but you'd end up with a zero byte file as you wrote nothing to the stream.

As you are not using `NewAccount` at all, removing those lines will allow `File.AppendAllText` to complete without error, and... append all the text you expect, which would be the values for first and last names, email and password.

Answer (score 0):

I try, it work

Don't open stream when you not used

File name include directory

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SignUp();
    }

    const string filename = "Workout.txt";
    static string[] SignUp()
    {
        string[] privinfo = new string[4];

        privinfo[0] = "First Name:";
        privinfo[1] = "Last Name: ";
        privinfo[2] = "Email: ";
        privinfo[3] = "Password: ";

        File.AppendAllText(Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, filename), privinfo[0] + ", " + privinfo[1] + "," + privinfo[2] + "," + privinfo[3] + Environment.NewLine);

        return privinfo;
    }
}
```

Run 2 times

file content is

```
First Name:, Last Name: ,Email: ,Password: 
First Name:, Last Name: ,Email: ,Password:
```

Comment: I think OP wants values, not labels.

Comment: So I just test File.AppendAllText, I don't need Console.ReadLine